# Rust macro generate enum from another enum

Tags: enums, rust, macros, metaprogramming

I am trying to solve a problem with code duplication to make it less error-prone.

I'm working with different Data Sources each with some specific properties. Here is how my data model looks like:

```
mod sources {
    pub struct Ds1;
    pub struct Ds2;
    //hundreds more

    pub trait DsTypeTrait{
        type Input;
        type Output;
    }

    impl DsTypeTrait for Ds1 {
        type Input = u32;
        type Output = u32;
    }

    impl DsTypeTrait for Ds2 {
        type Input = String;
        type Output = String;
    }

    //etc...

    enum DataSource{
        Ds1(Ds1),
        Ds2(Ds2),
        //...
    }
}
```

So any time somebody wants to add support for a new data source they need to add it to the `enum DataSource`. The **PROBLEM** with the solution is that if another module contains some custom data format for, e.g. `DataSource` communications it would be required to add the DataSource in the 2 places which is extremely error-prone. For example:

```
mod some_other {
    use super::sources::*;

    struct DataSourceDataInputOutput<Ds: DsTypeTrait>{
        input: <Ds as DsTypeTrait>::Input,
        output: <Ds as DsTypeTrait>::Output
    }

    enum DataSourceIO{
        Ds1(DataSourceDataInputOutput<Ds1>),
        Ds2(DataSourceDataInputOutput<Ds2>)
        //Extremely easy to forget to add here
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** Given the `enum DataSource` is it possible to write a macro to generate `enum DataSourceIO` automatically and avoid modifying `enum DataSourceIO` manually each time a `new DataSource` is added?

Answer (score 0):

It seems enum parsing is a complicated issue so it is reasonable to move the DataSource actual declaration in the macro itself. Here is what I came up with:

```
#[macro_use]
mod sources {
    macro_rules! data_sources {
        ($name:ident, $type:tt) => {
            enum $name{
                Ds1($type<Ds1>),
                Ds2($type<Ds2>)
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}

mod some_other {

    struct DataSourceDataInputOutput<Ds: DsTypeTrait>{
        input: <Ds as DsTypeTrait>::Input,
        output: <Ds as DsTypeTrait>::Output
    }
    
    data_sources!(Test, DataSourceDataInputOutput);

    fn test_fn() {
        let ds1io: DataSourceDataInputOutput<Ds1> = DataSourceDataInputOutput{
            input: 1,
            output: 2
        };
        let test = DataSourceIO::Ds1(ds1io);  //works ok
    }

}
```